# mobaxterm keyboard shortcut

Tags: shortcut, mobaxterm

I want to map some keys (say Ctrl-F1) to my most frequently password in mobaxterm that I run on Windows 10. Is there a way for me to do that? I looked at keyboard shortcuts that mobaxterm has but it doesn't let me what I am looking for.

Sreekanth

Answer (score 0):

Mobaxterm has only a limited set of keyboard shortcuts already configured, only possibility is to change the key combinations for these preset actions.

If you want to paste your frequently used password with `Ctrl+F1`, then you can actually do this with a `Macro`

Go to
`Macros -> Record New Macro -> Enter your password in one line and then RETURN in next line -> Assign Hotkey(Ctrl+F1) to this Macro`

And you are done, everytime you use the hotkey in Mobaxterm, then password from Macro will be pasted to the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Ctrl + Space` to open the list of macros.